# Number of Matches Between Two Comma Separated Factors in a Data Frame

Tags: r, match

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
Row    ID1    ID2    Colors1        Colors2
1      1      2      Green, Blue    Red, Orange
2      1      3      Green, Orange  Orange, Red
```

I would like to create a calculation that tells me the count of colors in common between Colors1 and Colors2.  The desired result is the following:

```
Row    ID1    ID2    Colors1                Colors2         Common 
1      1      2      Green, Blue, Purple    Green, Purple   2     #Green, Purple
2      1      3      Green, Orange          Orange, Red     1     #Orange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
col1 <- strsplit(df$Colors1, ", ")
col2 <- strsplit(df$Colors2, ", ")
df$Common <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(x) length(intersect(col1[[x]], col2[[x]])))
```

## Example

```
df <- data.frame(Colors1 = c('Green, Blue', 'Green, Blue, Purple'), Colors2 = c('Green, Purple', 'Orange, Red'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
col1 <- strsplit(df$Colors1, ", ")
col2 <- strsplit(df$Colors2, ", ")
df$Common <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(x) length(intersect(col1[[x]], col2[[x]])))
df
#               Colors1         Colors2   Common
# 1         Green, Blue   Green, Purple        1
# 2 Green, Blue, Purple   Orange, Red          0
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked.  The sapply statement is difficult for me to understand - any further explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: More specifically, why is sapply required?  Why doesn't the code length(intersect(col1, col2)) work?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to treat the first column as a regular expression to search in the second column and make use of the "stringi" package to facilitate the vectorized searching of the patterns.

```
df <- structure(list(Colors1 = c("Green, Blue, Purple", "Green, Blue", 
"Green, Blue, Purple"), Colors2 = c("Green, Purple", "Green, Purple", 
"Orange, Red")), .Names = c("Colors1", "Colors2"), row.names = c("2", 
"21", "3"), class = "data.frame")

df
#                Colors1       Colors2
# 2  Green, Blue, Purple Green, Purple
# 21         Green, Blue Green, Purple
# 3  Green, Blue, Purple   Orange, Red

library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(df$Colors2, gsub(", ", "|", df$Colors1))
# [[1]]
# [1] "Green"  "Purple"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Green"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] NA

stri_count_regex(df$Colors2, gsub(", ", "|", df$Colors1))
# [1] 2 1 0
```

Basically, what I've done there is use `gsub` to convert the "Colors1" column to a regular expression search pattern that looks like `"Green|Blue|Purple"` instead of `"Green, Blue, Purple"` and used that as the search pattern in each of the "stringi" functions I demonstrated above.

Comment: You could use some `stri_replace` function :)