# Partial Match Between Two Comma Separated Factors in a Data Frame

Tags: r, matching, partial

As the title suggested, my goal is to do partial match between two factors (with comma seperated values) in seperate data frames that have at least two matching elements

I have two dataframes like this:

df1

````r
structure(list(ID = c(55, 153, 274, 380, 34, 156), value = c("30002, 10057, 10012, 30045, 10065, 10207, 10013, 20056, 20024, 13026, 10032, 10031", 
"10026, 10051, 10010, 10302", "10004, 10133, 10103", "10009, 10035", 
"10003, 10202, 10319, 10421, 10025, 10033, 10045, 10036, 10049, 10055, 10062, 10069, 10083, 10086, 10089, 10090, 10099, 10100, 10102, 10103, 10112, 10114, 10120, 10125, 10126, 10128, 10144, 10148, 10149, 10150, 10158, 10159, 11330, 10035, 13508, 12003, 10124, 100266, 11302, 15305, 10240, 25024, 23003, 25204, 25343, 23058, 22007, 25278, 25204, 30117, 25346, 22324, 25325, 25133, 25229", 
"11002, 11107, 13340, 10344")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df2
```r
structure(list(ID = c(75, 412, 289, 214, 48, 222), value = c("30002, 10041, 10031, 20024, 13026", 
"10026, 10040", "10004, 10133", "10023, 10025, 10314, 10143", 
"10001, 10125, 10126, 10128", 
"10012, 10020, 10344")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
````

As shown above: 1) the ID is not in order and I sorted them by column "value", 2) number of elements in each row can be different, 3) element inside a "list" can be out of order 4) The original dataframe is large, so I think there might be multiple match, so I would like to output match count as well

***NOTE that here I ordered the dataset by "value" so it look like they are matched line by line but it's actually not the case if you look at the whole dataset, the goal is really to look for matches item by item.

I want my resulting df to return both ID of the dataframe and matching element if any two lists have at least two common elements: For example ID 55 in df1 and ID 75 in df1- would  return something like

```r
ID_1 ID_2  Matched_element     Match_count
75   55    30002,20024,13026   3
```

I tried to use string split to make the variable value "list", but this still doesn't help with my partial match.

```r
df1<-str_split(df1$value, ",")
df2<-str_split(df2$value, ",")
```

[Number of Matches Between Two Comma Separated Factors in a Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725023/number-of-matches-between-two-comma-separated-factors-in-a-data-frame)
This question is very similar to the quetsion I'm asking, but can't solve my problem because it is matching on a row-by-row basis.

Comment: please, output the dataframes using `dput`

Comment: *"As shown above: 1) the ID is completely scrambled"* I'm not sure I understand what you mean by scrambled. It's also not clear to me what the `"..."` denote in your second dataset. Do you actually have rows that contain only a set of dots? I second the previous commenter's request to post minimal data in a reproducible and unambiguous way using `dput`. If unsure, take a look at how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi @djangodjango, welcome to Stack!  As other folks have mentioned, if you can do ```dput(df1)``` and post that in your question (use the "edit" option), that will greatly help others try to answer your question. Trying to recreate your first one, I'd start with something like this ```ID <-  c(1,2,3)```, ```Value <- c("27003, 47013, 17010, 17129, 75339, 17140", "10325, 10049, 10002, 10009, 10010", "19007, 19000")```, ```df1 <- data.frame(ID, Value)``` but does your dataframe have factors, etc?

Comment: And if you have a large dataframe and just want to post a certain number of lines of it, you can use ```head()``` as well. So to provide the first 3 lines of your dataframe  you would use ```dput(head(df1,3))```

Comment: @RussThomas It doesn't have factors. I have edited the part, Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @MauritsEvers I have rephrase the part. it simply means that I can't match by ID because the data is not in order in any way.

Comment: @dangodango is for loop good with you ?

Comment: @OmarAbdEl-Naser I still want to try fuzzy-join, but I don't think computing time is an issue for me for now-- so for loop is fine!

Comment: @dangodango i'll try to remove the for loop with another functions, it's just trial to prove the idea

Comment: @dangodango There are inconsistencies in your example output; that aside, this seems to be in essence a straightforward inner join. Please see my post below.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite get your expected output. There seem to be inconsistencies/typos

1. You say that *" For example ID 55 in df1 and ID 75 in df1- "*, yet in your expected output `ID_2 = 55` and `ID_1 = 75`. Shouldn't it be `ID_1 = 55` (since it's coming from `df1`) and `ID_2 = 75` (from `df2`)?
2. Why is there no `10031` value in the example output you give? `value = 10031` is in both `df1` and `df2` for `ID_1 = 55` and `ID_2 = 75`.

The inconsistencies aside, this seems to be a fairly straightforward `inner_join`:

```
library(tidyverse)
inner_join(
    df1 %>% separate_rows(value),
    df2 %>% separate_rows(value),
    by = "value", suffix = c("_1", "_2")) %>%
    group_by(ID_1, ID_2) %>%
    summarise(value = toString(value))
## A tibble: 7 x 3
## Groups:   ID_1 [5]
#   ID_1  ID_2 value
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1    34    48 10125, 10126, 10128
#2    34   214 10025
#3    55    75 30002, 20024, 13026, 10031
#4    55   222 10012
#5   153   412 10026
#6   156   222 10344
#7   274   289 10004, 10133
```

Explanation: We use `separate_rows` to separate comma-separated entries in column `value`, then perform an `inner_join` on `value`; we then `group_by` `ID_1` and `ID_2` and summarise entries by comma-concatenating `value`s using `toString`.

---

To select only those rows where you have at least 3 matching `value`s you can do

```
inner_join(
    df1 %>% separate_rows(value),
    df2 %>% separate_rows(value),
    by = "value", suffix = c("_1", "_2")) %>%
    group_by(ID_1, ID_2) %>%
    filter(length(value) > 2) %>%
    summarise(
        matched_element = toString(value),
        match_count = length(value))
## A tibble: 2 x 4
## Groups:   ID_1 [2]
#   ID_1  ID_2 matched_element            match_count
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                            <int>
#1    34    48 10125, 10126, 10128                  3
#2    55    75 30002, 20024, 13026, 10031           4
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know inner join can work :)  Yes, you were right, the result has some typo, but this work like a charm

Comment: @dangodango please thump the answer up and make it as answer

Comment: @dangodango As Omar Abd El-Naser suggests, check out the StackOverflow help center article on [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using nested `map`

```
library(stringr)
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(55, 153, 274, 380, 34, 156), value = c("30002, 10057, 10012, 30045, 10065, 10207, 10013, 20056, 20024, 13026, 10032, 10031", 
                                                             "10026, 10051, 10010, 10302", "10004, 10133, 10103", "10009, 10035", 
                                                             "10003, 10202, 10319, 10421, 10025, 10033, 10045, 10036, 10049, 10055, 10062, 10069, 10083, 10086, 10089, 10090, 10099, 10100, 10102, 10103, 10112, 10114, 10120, 10125, 10126, 10128, 10144, 10148, 10149, 10150, 10158, 10159, 11330, 10035, 13508, 12003, 10124, 100266, 11302, 15305, 10240, 25024, 23003, 25204, 25343, 23058, 22007, 25278, 25204, 30117, 25346, 22324, 25325, 25133, 25229", 
                                                             "11002, 11107, 13340, 10344")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                       "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID1 = c(75, 412, 289, 214, 48, 222), value1 = c("30002, 10041, 10031, 20024, 13026", 
                                                             "10026, 10040", "10004, 10133", "10023, 10025, 10314, 10143", 
                                                             "10001, 10125, 10126, 10128", 
                                                             "10012, 10020, 10344")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                             ), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
#Change value column into a list of numeric values
df1 <-  df1 %>% mutate(x = map(value,function(x) (as.numeric(unlist(str_split(x,","))))))
df2 <-  df2 %>% mutate(x1 = map(value1,function(x) (as.numeric(unlist(str_split(x,","))))))

#Combine dataframes
df <- cbind(df1,df2)

Final_Data <- enframe(map(df$x,~ map(df$x1,~.y[.y %in% .x],.y = .x))) %>% unnest() %>%  
        mutate(ID_1 = rep(df$ID,each = 6),ID_2 = rep(df$ID1,times=6),
               Length = lengths(value) ) %>% filter(Length > 2 )
```

Comment: Thanks! It turns out it take some time to run the for loop, though. But this also works! Thank you very much for taking your time writing this

Comment: @dangodango i changed the for loop with map if u still interested :D